# How to fix Heap Corruption Detected: after Normal block

Tags: c++

"CRT detected that the application wrote to memory end of heap buffer" error. It crashes when it arrives

i am having problem when it calls destruct-or function. if i comment out the destruct-or function it works fine.

```
class Polynomial
{
private:
    int totalTerms;//Total terms in a Polynomial
    int* coeff;//to save array of coefficients
    int* exp; //to save array of exponents
public:
    Polynomial()
    {
        this->totalTerms = 0;
        this->coeff = NULL;
        this->exp = NULL;
    }
    Polynomial(int totalTerms, int* coeff, int* exp)
    {
        this->totalTerms = totalTerms;
        this->coeff = new int[totalTerms];
        this->exp = new int[totalTerms];
        for (int i = 0; i < totalTerms; i++)
        {
            this->coeff[i] = 0;
            this->exp[i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < totalTerms; i++)
        {
            this->coeff[i] = coeff[i];
            this->exp[i] = exp[i];
        }
    }

    Polynomial(const Polynomial&);
    ~Polynomial();
    void Print();
    Polynomial Add(const Polynomial&);
    const Polynomial& operator=(const Polynomial&);
    
};
Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial& RHS) 
{

    this->totalTerms = RHS.totalTerms;
    this->coeff = new int[totalTerms];
    this->exp = new int[totalTerms];

    for (int i = 0; i < totalTerms; i++)
    {
        this->coeff[i] = RHS.coeff[i];
        this->exp[i] = RHS.exp[i];
    }

}
Polynomial::~Polynomial()
{
    if (coeff != NULL)
        delete coeff;
    if (exp != NULL)
        delete exp;
}
void Polynomial::Print()//Prints P1 = x^4+2x^2+5
{
    for (int i = 0; i < totalTerms; i++)
    {
        if (coeff[i] != 0) {
            cout << coeff[i];
            if (exp[i] != 0)
                cout << "x^" << exp[i];
            if (i != totalTerms - 1)
                cout << " + ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
Polynomial Polynomial::Add(const Polynomial& RHS)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    Polynomial resultantPolynomial;
    Polynomial lhs = *this;
    while (i < sizeof(lhs.exp) && j < sizeof(RHS.exp)) {
        if (lhs.exp[i] > RHS.exp[j]) {

            k++; i++;
        }
        else if (lhs.exp[i] == RHS.exp[j])
        {
            k++;
            i++;
            j++;

        }
        else {
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }

    resultantPolynomial.totalTerms = k - 1;
    resultantPolynomial.coeff = new int[resultantPolynomial.totalTerms];
    resultantPolynomial.exp = new int[resultantPolynomial.totalTerms];
    for (int i = 0; i < resultantPolynomial.totalTerms; i++)
    {
        resultantPolynomial.coeff[i] = 0;
        resultantPolynomial.exp[i] = 0;
    }

    i = 0; j = 0; k = 0;
    while (i < sizeof(lhs.exp) && j < sizeof(RHS.exp)) {
        if (lhs.exp[i] > RHS.exp[j]) {
            resultantPolynomial.exp[k] = lhs.exp[i];
            resultantPolynomial.coeff[k] = resultantPolynomial.coeff[k] + lhs.coeff[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else if (lhs.exp[i] == RHS.exp[j])
        {
            resultantPolynomial.exp[k] = RHS.exp[j];
            resultantPolynomial.coeff[k] = lhs.coeff[i] + RHS.coeff[j];
            j++;
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else {
            resultantPolynomial.exp[k] = RHS.exp[j];
            resultantPolynomial.coeff[k] = resultantPolynomial.coeff[k] + RHS.coeff[j];
            j++;
            k++;

        }
    }

    //for (int i = 0; i < resultantPolynomial.totalTerms; i++)
    //{
    //  if (i < resultantPolynomial.totalTerms) {
    //      resultantPolynomial.coeff[i] = resultantPolynomial.coeff[i];
    //      resultantPolynomial.exp[i] = resultantPolynomial.exp[i];
    //  }
    //}
    return (resultantPolynomial);
}
const Polynomial& Polynomial::operator=(const Polynomial& RHS)
{

    if (&RHS != this)   //Avoid self-assignment
    {
        //De-allocate previous memory and allocate new memory IF REQUIRED
        this->totalTerms = 0;
        if (this->coeff != NULL)
            delete this->coeff;
        if (this->exp != NULL)
            delete this->exp;

        this->totalTerms = RHS.totalTerms;
        this->coeff = new int[totalTerms];
        this->exp = new int[totalTerms];
        for (int i = 0; i < totalTerms; i++)
        {
            this->coeff[i] = RHS.coeff[i];
            this->exp[i] = RHS.exp[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;


}
int main()
{
    int coeff_P1[] = { 1,2,5 }; //Coefficients for Polynomial P1
    int exp_P1[] = { 4,2,0 };   //Exponents for Polynomial P1

    int coeff_P2[] = { 4,3 };   //Coefficients for Polynomial P2
    int exp_P2[] = { 6,2 }; //Exponents for Polynomial P2

    Polynomial P1(3, coeff_P1, exp_P1);//Creates P1 with 3 terms (P1 = 1x^4 + 2x^2 + 5x^0 )
    Polynomial P2(2, coeff_P2, exp_P2);//Creates P2 with 2 terms (P2 = 4x^6 + 3x^2)

    cout << "P1 = "; P1.Print(); //Prints P1 = x^4+2x^2+5
    cout << "P2 = "; P2.Print(); //Prints P2 = 4x^6+3x^2

    Polynomial P3 = P1.Add(P2); //Adds P1 and P2 and saves result in P3. 

    cout << "P3 = "; P3.Print();    //Prints P3 = 4x^6+x^4+5x^2+5   
    P3 = P1;
    cout << "P3 = "; P3.Print();

}
```

This is the out put i get when i comment out the destruct-or function

> P1 = x^4+2x^2+5
>
> P2 = 4x^6+3x^2
>
> P3 = 4x^6+x^4+5x^2+5
>
> P3 = x^4+2x^2+5

But when i use destruct-or function the output on screen is

> P1 = x^4+2x^2+5
>
> P2 = 4x^6+3x^2

Comment: E.g. `sizeof(lhs.exp)` is wrong, it will not give you the number of elements allocated, only tell you how large the pointer itself is. On a 64-bit system it's typically `8` bytes which is what will be reported.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think this comment is what is in this case making the program fail. It will iterate 8 times no matter what; give a shorter vector and it'll be an out of bounds access.

Comment: on a general note.. Q: "how to fix heap corruption" A: stop writing to memory you didn't allocate or which you already freed. Easier said than done, this is actually one of those bugs which were haunting generations of C and C++ programmers, before the tools like valgrind, unit testing and static analyzers appeared. It may feel like overkill to learn yet another tool for simple school assignment, then again be stuck on thing like this for a week (in the age before Internet), and you would consider spending two days learning how to use valgrind as pure miracle and blessing... (you should do it)

Answer (score 3):

The main problem here, I think, is that you use `new[]` and then match it with `delete`.

You should always match `new[]` with `delete[]` (and non-array `new` with `delete`).

Non-matching allocation and deallocation leads to *undefined behavior*.

The best solution is to stop using pointers and dynamic allocation, and use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Nicked your `delete[]`. Have an upvote for good feelings!

Comment: @Bathsheba You're welcome. And thanks. Makes me feel warm all over... :D

Comment: can not use vector it is assignment requirement from teacher

Comment: @AkhwandAbdulKareem Then the correct solution in modern C++ is to write a vector class yourself (following the [rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))) and then use that for the actual problem (following the advice in the answers given here). Doing manual memory management in a class that is supposed to represent polynomial violates the single responsibility principle.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
int* coeff;
int* exp;
```

with

```
std::vector<int> coeff;
std::vector<int> exp;
```

`totalTerms` is then redundant - you can use the `size` method on one of your vectors.

Then remove all your explicit memory calls, your constructors, and assignment operator as the ones the compiler will generate for you will be adequate. Use `.at` rather than `[` for element access so at least you get a runtime exception rather than undefined behaviour if you attempt an out of bounds access. Your code will then work.

There's rarely a need to model an array with an explicit dynamically allocated array; it's a magnet for bugs, such as the ones you have. At least one of your bugs is due to a inappropriate `sizeof`, another is your using `delete` instead of `delete[]`.